# Combinatorial databases

Tags: co.combinatorics, soft-question, big-list, online-resources, oeis

At one point, I remember being excited by seeing the website [Encyclopedia of Combinatorial Structures](http://algo.inria.fr/encyclopedia/) as an extension of Sloane's [Online Integer Sequence Database](http://oeis.org/) site. Unfortunately, the site (ECS) has already become largely defunct.

I would very much like to see a searchable database of combinatorial objects online -- ideally, not just as a site with pictures or counts of these structures, but a database with downloadable files in SOME format containing usable, interpretable copies of these enumerated sets (a la the [ARG database](http://mivia.unisa.it/datasets/graph-database/) for labeled and unlabeled graphs.)

Broadly requested, does anyone know of such a site or sites? In particular, I am asking as part of a search for lists of polyominos stored as matrices (rather than just displayed as a picture), but I'd be curious if such an encyclopaedic site (or sites) exists -- and if not in general, then I would love to be pointed to a few databases of specialized combinatorial structures.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is exactly what you're looking for, but http://www.findstat.org/ is another nice combinatorial database.

Comment: Does the ATLAS of finite simple groups count?

Comment: A very similar topic was discussed by Bridget Tenner at Richard Stanley's 70th birthday conference.  She refers to this sort of thing as a "fingerprint database." http://math.mit.edu/stanley70/Site/Slides/Tenner.pdf  You might want to contact Tenner to see if there have been any recent developments.

Comment: I misread the post title as meaning databases seen as an interesting pure combinatorial structure, which they are (as sets of interrelated relations) !

Answer (score 13):

Not related to polyominos, but I like House of Graphs: https://houseofgraphs.org

It allows you to search by graph6 code, so if you find an interesting graph, you can check whether that graph has arisen in other contexts.

Answer (score 12):

1. La Jolla Covering repository: https://www.dmgordon.org/cover/
2. Information system on graph classes and their inclusions: [http://www.graphclasses.org](http://www.graphclasses.org/index.html)

Answer (score 8):

To expand Thomas Kalinowski's answer graphclasses.org can be used in sage http://sagemath.org/

Download the latest database and do custom queries in python, possibly adding inclusions, new classes, etc.

Check `sage.graphs.isgci.graph_classes`

Comment: And if I may say the (already very old) branch at http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/14396 would improve the current interface !!!

Answer (score 7):

How about [FindStat](http://www.findstat.org)? It is a database of combinatorial statistics,
i.e. maps from combinatorial objects to integers.

Another page I just found has a [database with posets](http://lists-of-posets.math.unc.edu/),
which is quite nice.

Comment: FindStat was mentioned by Sam Hopkins in a comment.

Comment: Oh, I missed that.

Answer (score 5):

There is a database of linear block codes and quantum codes at http://www.codetables.de

There's a design database at http://designtheory.org/database/

Answer (score 4):

A similar question was asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23748/where-on-the-internet-i-can-find-database-of-graphs/23761#23761). At the time I suggested Donald Knuth's Stanford GraphBase: A Platform for Combinatorial Computing (1994, 2009) and the accompanying [website](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/sgb.html).

See also [The Stony Brook Algorithm Repository](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~algorith/implement/graphbase/implement.shtml).

Answer (score 4):

Andries Brouwer's collection of strongly regular graphs: [http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/graphs/srg/srgtab.html](http://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/graphs/srg/srgtab.html)

Eric Moorhouse's collections of finite projective planes and generalized polygons: http://ericmoorhouse.org/pub/planes/, http://ericmoorhouse.org/pub/genpoly/

Gordon Royle's collection of combinatorial objects: [http://staffhome.ecm.uwa.edu.au/~00013890/data.html](http://staffhome.ecm.uwa.edu.au/%7E00013890/data.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yoshitake Matsumoto maintains some [databases of matroids](http://www-imai.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~ymatsu/matroid/index.html).  Gordon Royle also has a database of matroids that might contain some data not in Matsumoto's database, but I can't seem to find it on [his webpage](http://staffhome.ecm.uwa.edu.au/~00013890/).  The URL in [his paper with Mayhew](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702316) does not seem to work any more.  You might have to contact Royle or Mayhew.

Answer (score 2):

The Combinatorial Object Server (CoS) can generate perms/combs, sets/multisets, partitions, DeBuijn seqs/Lyndon words/necklaces, graphs, and a few others, all through a web interface. Unfortunately, it only typically works well for queries that have relatively few results. (It will truncate the responses to 1000 objects)

http://combos.org

(Edit: referring back to your original specific request, it can also produce all polyominoes of fixed size or all polyomino covering of a user-specified shape, and several others, and output as either text or images)

Comment: The original COS website is broken since many years, but the new one on http://combos.org is fully functional and brings back much of the original content.

Answer (score 2):

[Encyclopedia of Combinatorial Polytope Sequences](https://sforcey.github.io/sf34/hedra.htm) by Stefan Forcey

Answer (score 1):

SMAPO is a library of linear descriptions of low-dimensional 0/1-polytopes connected with small instances of combinatorial optimization problems:

http://www.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/groups/comopt/software/SMAPO/

(I quoted the description from the website.)