# A centralised website for computational attempts in graph theory and metric geometry?

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, na.numerical-analysis, computer-algebra, online-resources

The set of questions below stems from [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236392/has-there-been-a-computer-search-for-a-5-chromatic-unit-distance-graph).

> 1) does a website exist that contains (at least links to) code and data files, with the aim to centralise computational results in graph theory (or more generally metric geometry), both definite ones and unsuccessful/partial ones?

(Note that the [Open Problem Garden website](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/) only lists statements and some recent references that are usually not of a computational flavor. The idea is to avoid wasting time repeating an ultimately unsuccessful approach.).

> 2) Are there examples of such type of website in other areas of mathematics?

Comment: graphclasses contains complexity results and relations:  http://graphclasses.org/

Comment: Related and not mentioned here yet: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23748/where-on-the-internet-i-can-find-database-of-graphs/294242#294242

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few websites with lists and/or databases of graphs, maps and polytopes.

- [House of graphs](https://hog.grinvin.org) has a searchable database of interesting graphs and aims to serve as a repository for lists of graphs and graph generators,
- [Encyclopedia of graphs](http://atlas.gregas.eu) is an online encyclopedia of graph collections with some data about different families of graphs,
- [Database of graphs in combinatorica format](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~skiena/combinatorica/graphs/),
- [Encyclopedia of Finite Graphs](https://github.com/thoppe/Encyclopedia-of-Finite-Graphs) is a "set of tools and data to compute all known invariants for simple connected graphs".

There are several censuses of symmetric objects (for example [Marston Conder](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~conder/), [Dimitri Leemans](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~dleemans/resources.html), [Primož Potočnik](http://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~potocnik/work.htm)).

I would also like to know about other websites of similar nature out there, since I'm working on one myself. It's still an early stage [project](http://www.discretezoo.xyz), but has some use already. It aims to one day be able to provide a platform for computational attempts for all sorts of discrete objects (you can see some features for the exploratory aspect on the website).

Comment: Well done for getting the site up and running. I minor bug that I thought you wouldn't mind me mentioning: the closing 'x' button doesn't seem to work for the selected filters at the moment, at least not for me. I'm running Google Chrome.

Comment: Thanks @JamesSmith!  I let the ball drop a bit on the live website - I'm adding a bunch of new things that require a more involved redesign and was focusing on that.  I'll see if I can reproduce the bug and fix it.

Comment: i know *exactly* what you mean :0)